# Performance of writing the update logic in rows of editable table

Tags: reactjs

I have a table React component with rows containg sub-component containing an input textbox inside it.
When updating the value of the textbox, I run some logic and call a backend api.
Is there any recommendation **not** to put this logic inside the sub component ?
like this :

```
function Table(){

return (
   <table>
     <tr><td>abcd</td> {/* ... */} <td><InputComponent id={item.id} /></td></tr>
    {/* ... big table... 1000+ rows ! */} 
    </table>
)}

function InputComponent({id}){

  function update(){
    if (value_has_changed)
     ...
     fetch( `http://backendURL/update/${id}` )
     ...
  }

return (
   <input type="textbox" onChange={update} value="xyz" />
)}
```

My first intuition was to put the update function on the top (Table) component and pass it as a  prop to InputComponent.
But it's harder to read and I don't know if it's even more efficient.
Is the update function "copied" a 1000 times by doing like in the upper example ?

Comment: If the function is strictly related to that component, put it there and wrap it in useCallback passing the proper dependecies. Documentation: https://react.dev/reference/react/useCallback

Comment: Thanks. I will try this. Still, I can’t find if passing a function as a prop is equivalent to declaring it inside the component, in terms of performance